# Swift JSON "POST" Request Data Array

Tags: arrays, json, swift, post, struct

I can't remove the array from the data output, have tried to define a struct with the number of quotes I get from the data and tried to enter it but I can't as I have to remove the array brackets from the JSON Response first. Been stuck here for sometime now, First time using JSON POST type.

```
if let requestUrl = url {
            // Prepare URL Request Object
            var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            // HTTP Request Parameters which will be sent in HTTP Request Body
            let postString = ["freq": freqId]
            // Set HTTP Request Body
            request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postString, options: [] );
            // Perform HTTP Request
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                // Check for Error
                if let error = error {
                    self.delegate?.didGetError(error: error)
                    return
                }
                // Convert HTTP Response Data to a String
                if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print(dataString)
                    let quotes = DataModel(quotes: dataString)
                    self.delegate?.didGetData(data: quotes)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
        else {
            fatalError()
        }
```

Response :

```
["10 years from now , you'll look back and say I'm glad I started trading","I always define my risk and I don't have to worry about it","For trading success , there's a realization that when you don't care , you do well and when you try too hard , you don't .","Necessity never made a good bargain.","When a falling stock becomes a screaming buy because it cannot conceivably drop further , try to buy it thirty percent lower .","There are infinite number of ways to make money in markets & in life , Find ONE that works for you.","Get comfortable with being uncomfortable !.","The markets are always changing , and they are always the same.","You can't control how you feel . But you can always to choose how you act !","If what you're looking for is an excuse you'll find one !"]
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf2YL.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Post code as text and never as an image, text can be searched and copy/pasted into an editor/IDE for people who wants to help you.

Comment: You have converted your response to stringify JSON. I guess you should convert it to Swift data types like Dictionary or Array as per need.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like the response is an array and not a string so change your handling of `data` to

```
guard let data = data else {
    //error handling...
    return
}

do {
    if let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String] {
        let quotes = DataModel(quotes: array)
        self.delegate?.didGetData(data: quotes)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
    //error handling...
}
```

This assumes `DataModel` can be initialised with an array, if not you need to do something like below to merge the elements of the array into a string first

```
let string = array.joined(separator: " ")
```

Looking at the screenshot I suspect it is not that easy but the best way to handle the content of the array is beyond this question